# How does one alter the sidebar of a MediaWiki site?

Tags: mediawiki

The default left sidebar for a MediaWiki powered sidebar contains such links as "Random Page" and "Current Events." I want to hide these.

Is there a way to do this aside from using CSS (`display:none;`)?
Correspondingly, is there a way to add pages to this list?

Would this require editing any PhP files?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The MediaWiki manual](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aInterface/Sidebar) may have the information you're looking for. (That was the top hit for "mediawiki customize sidebar" on a search engine.)

Comment: Wow, thanks. Looking at the top hit for a search engine query is such a great strategy.

Answer (score 8):

No coding needed, just edit the page "[MediaWiki:Sidebar](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aInterface/Sidebar)" in your wiki.  Admin rights required, obviously.

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative is to just change the link to:

```
http://yourdomain/yourwiki/index.php?title=MediaWiki:Sidebar&action=submit
```